# How to use data in nsmutablearray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7, nsmutablearray

```
  ( 
   (
           {

        "id" = 4;
       "title" = abc
   },
           {

        "id" = 5;
       "title" = xyz;
   },
           {
       "id" = 7;
           "title" = "pqr";

        }
   )
    )
```

this data in `NSMutableArray` and i am getting this data through id or title that time i am getting only get title abc how to get all data in `NSMutableArray`

My code is :-

```
 for(int counter =0 ; counter < [tempData count];counter++)
  {
      NSMutableArray *tempData1 = [tempData objectAtIndex:counter];

      NSString *str_title = [tempData1 objectAtIndex:counter][@"title"];

    [nsm_temp addObject:str_title];
}
```

`nsm_temp` is the `NSMutableArray`

Comment: You have an array with an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tempData` is the outer array you could do:

```
NSArray *tempData = ... // the outer array
NSArray *innerArray = tempData[0];
for (NSDictionary *dict in innerArray) {
    NSString *title = dict[@"title"];
    [nsm_temp addObject:title];
}
```

Comment: use NSArray *innerArray = [tempData firstObject]; instead tempData[0];